# Element is not clicking on openBravo Application

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm working an OpenBravo application. I'm facing a problem with clicking an element when tried with a text id class. I'm able to find the element but the element is not clicking on that button.

I used the `click()` event with the action `sendKeys()` in JavaScript but it is still not working.

Comment: Got to give more details like relevant html source and code you have attempted. Also Javascript is mentioned in the post but you have tagged it with Java.

Answer (score -1):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("terminal_containerWindow_pointOfSale_DWCRM_UI_EmployeeIdPopup_bodyButtons_okButton")).click();
```

Html format is

```
<div id="terminal_containerWindow_pointOfSale_DWCRM_UI_EmployeeIdPopup_bodyButtons_control">
    <input style="width: 100%;margin-bottom:0px;background-color: #E8E8E8;width:300px" readonly="readonly" class="enyo-input input" id="terminal_containerWindow_pointOfSale_DWCRM_UI_EmployeeIdPopup_bodyButtons_EmployeeName" type="text" value="Kanika Sachdeva">
    <br id="terminal_containerWindow_pointOfSale_DWCRM_UI_EmployeeIdPopup_bodyButtons_control2">
    <input style="width: 100%;margin-bottom:0px;width:300px" maxlength="15" class="enyo-input input" id="terminal_containerWindow_pointOfSale_DWCRM_UI_EmployeeIdPopup_bodyButtons_EMPLOYEEID" placeholder="Enter Employee Id ..." type="text">
    <br id="terminal_containerWindow_pointOfSale_DWCRM_UI_EmployeeIdPopup_bodyButtons_control3">
    <button class="enyo-tool-decorator btnlink btnlink-gray modal-dialog-button" id="terminal_containerWindow_pointOfSale_DWCRM_UI_EmployeeIdPopup_bodyButtons_okButton">OK</button>
</div>
```